# How to connect 2 hot wire to a 2 pole MCB?

Tags: voltage

how can i connect 2 hot wires to a 2 pole MCB? What is the output of 2 pole MCB ? Will it be the same as 2 hot wire output or can connect to a LIVE and NEUTRAL terminal?

Comment: @RonBeyer Miniature Circuit Breaker

Comment: Definitely the DIY forum or home improvements, then.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Are you talking about tandem circuit breakers where 2 breakers fit inn1 position?

Answer (score 1):

The output of an MCB is indicated by voltmeter testing.  I'm serious.  That's what Code says, you're not allowed to guess at voltages, you must measure.  Because a MCB goes into a panelboard aka loadcenter aka service panel, and the voltage depends on how it is wired.

I'm planning to install a 2-pole Square D QO panel next week where one pole will be neutral because of a peculiar requirement.

Europeans in North America, or anything having to do with the Philippines, is likely to have this issue as well, and it will vary depending on where you are in the Philippines.  That is one place you cannot make assumptions.